# Функция не видит виджеты внутри класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, виджет

Прощу помощи. По какой такой неведомой мне причине, вот таким образом внутри класса можно обратиться к 'w1'

```py
class Starter:

    A = 40
    B = 100
    C = 70

    win = Tk()
    win.title='Press'
    win.geometry("300x300")



    lb = resp().make_label(10,2,win,sider = 'top',bg = 'gold')
    bt = resp().make_button(w = 5,h = 1,frame_name=win,sider = 'bottom')

    w1 = Scale(win,width = 100,from_ = 0, to = 100, orient = HORIZONTAL)

    w1.get()


    canv = Canvas(win,width = 200,height = 200,bg = 'blue')
    canv.create_polygon((A,B),(A,C),(B,C),outline = 'black',fill = "yellow")
    canv.pack()
    w1.pack()
```

А вот так нельзя.

```py
class Starter:

    A = 40
    B = 100
    C = 70

    def ab_t(event):
        w1.get()

    win = Tk()
    win.title='Press'
    win.geometry("300x300")



    lb = resp().make_label(10,2,win,sider = 'top',bg = 'gold')
    bt = resp().make_button(w = 5,h = 1,frame_name=win,sider = 'bottom')

    w1 = Scale(win,width = 100,from_ = 0, to = 100, orient = HORIZONTAL)

    bt.bind("<Button-1>", ab_t)

    canv = Canvas(win,width = 200,height = 200,bg = 'blue')
    canv.create_polygon((A,B),(A,C),(B,C),outline = 'black',fill = "yellow")
    canv.pack()
    w1.pack()
```

Comment: в методах надо писать this. перед переменными класса для доступа к ним

Comment: в Python вроде self, а не this?

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с теорией [по классам и объектам](https://devpractice.ru/python-lesson-14-classes-and-objects/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно "готовите" классы. Код должен быть в методах класса, а не на верхнем уровне классов. На верхнем уровне должны только прописываться поля, общие для всех объектов данного класса.

То что вы сейчас делаете можно делать через обычные функции:

```
from tkinter import *


def Starter():
    A = 40
    B = 100
    C = 70

    def ab_t(event):
        python(w1.get())

    win = Tk()
    win.title='Press'
    win.geometry("300x300")

    # lb = resp().make_label(10,2,win,sider = 'top',bg = 'gold')
    # bt = resp().make_button(w = 5,h = 1,frame_name=win,sider = 'bottom')
    bt = Button(win)

    w1 = Scale(win,width = 100,from_ = 0, to = 100, orient = HORIZONTAL)

    bt.bind("<Button-1>", ab_t)

    canv = Canvas(win,width = 200,height = 200,bg = 'blue')
    canv.create_polygon((A,B),(A,C),(B,C),outline = 'black',fill = "yellow")
    canv.pack()
    w1.pack()

    win.mainloop()


Starter()
```

То же самое через условно "правильный" класс:

```
from tkinter import *


class Starter:
    def __init__(self):
        A = 40
        B = 100
        C = 70

        def ab_t(event):
            print(w1.get())

        win = Tk()
        win.title='Press'
        win.geometry("300x300")

        # lb = resp().make_label(10,2,win,sider = 'top',bg = 'gold')
        # bt = resp().make_button(w = 5,h = 1,frame_name=win,sider = 'bottom')
        bt = Button(win)

        w1 = Scale(win,width = 100,from_ = 0, to = 100, orient = HORIZONTAL)

        bt.bind("<Button-1>", ab_t)

        canv = Canvas(win,width = 200,height = 200,bg = 'blue')
        canv.create_polygon((A,B),(A,C),(B,C),outline = 'black',fill = "yellow")
        canv.pack()
        w1.pack()

        win.mainloop()


Starter()
```

Или если нужно чтобы `ab_t` было отдельным методом, а не вложенной функцией:

```
from tkinter import *


class Starter:
    def ab_t(self, event):
        python(self.w1.get())

    def __init__(self):
        A = 40
        B = 100
        C = 70

        win = Tk()
        win.title='Press'
        win.geometry("300x300")

        # lb = resp().make_label(10,2,win,sider = 'top',bg = 'gold')
        # bt = resp().make_button(w = 5,h = 1,frame_name=win,sider = 'bottom')
        bt = Button(win)

        self.w1 = Scale(win,width = 100,from_ = 0, to = 100, orient = HORIZONTAL)

        bt.bind("<Button-1>", self.ab_t)

        canv = Canvas(win,width = 200,height = 200,bg = 'blue')
        canv.create_polygon((A,B),(A,C),(B,C),outline = 'black',fill = "yellow")
        canv.pack()
        self.w1.pack()

        win.mainloop()


Starter()
```

Comment: Спасибо за хорошее объяснение

Answer (score 0):

```
def ab_t(self, event):
    self.w1.get()
```

В методах классов первый аргумент всегда self(он работает как this)

Comment: так выдает ошибку.

Comment: Можно листинг ошибки?